# Different child views at specified position in a group

Tags: android, layout, parent-child, viewgroup

My real device and emulator are giving different child views for the same `ViewGroup` of the layout.

**Code:**

```
for(int i=0; i<((ViewGroup)viewGroup).getChildCount(); ++i) 
{
    View nextChild = ((ViewGroup)viewGroup).getChildAt(i);

    System.out.println("the next child is"+nextChild);
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

*Emulator-*

> the next child is android.widget.LinearLayout
>
> the next child is android.widget.Button

*Real device-*

> the next child is android.widget.NumberPicker
>
> the next child is android.widget.NumberPicker
>
> the next child is android.widget.Button
>
> the next child is

How can it be possible ?

I can see the following possibilities of getting different child views-

1) Different configurations for different devices

2) Real Device Versus Emulator

3) Other possibilities

Any ideas.. ?